# Get my location

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a ListFragment and I want to get the my location. In my Manifest I have added this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

and my ListFragment´s code is here, but not works:

```
public class ListaLugaresFragment extends ListFragment implements LocationListener {


    GoogleMap googleMap;
    Location location;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista, container, false);

         LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().LOCATION_SERVICE);
         lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);


         return v;

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), location.getLatitude()+""+location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23926311/not-getting-latitude-and-longitude-after-every-1-minute-in-android/23926531#23926531 it helps you

Comment: you may need to write [a bit more code to obtain the location, esp GPS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23962769/android-gps-incorrect-location-data-on-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to know about **GPS, Network Provider, google MAP** to know getting location. Below example is for beginner to know how to get location(lanlat value) from the GPS and Network Provider

**Follow this link:**

[Getting location (latlong)](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/)

If you want to get a location name then u must know about SHA code and all.

**Follow this Link:**

[Getting location from googlemap](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLLk083vNjCXY-5Scs_pTTFlN9Cc-tmIDo)