# Receiving current location on Android

Tags: android, android-studio, location

I've been working on an app that needs to be location-aware, and I've noticed that there are two (or more) methods of receiving location: with Google Play services (as seen here developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html#GetLocation) and with Location Manager, Providers etc. (as seen here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html#locationapi_criteria).

What is the difference between these methods (if there is any)? Which one is more accurate?

edit: ok, I see that I sent the wrong link on the first thing. Won't this code (http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) give me location updates? Generally, what's the most accurate way to get my location?

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24118994/3292795

Answer (score 0):

The one with the GPS is accurate and that which is based on Network is not. Google Play Service use FUSE api to get the GPS location first, if the location is found (that's great), otherwise it will try to get location fix from Network Tower. In Short the one with GPS is accurate

Answer (score 0):

The first method provides the details of LastKnownLocation. ie. the last location received from GPS or network provider when you or other apps accessed the location services. After that there are chances you moved a lot and it need not be your current location. So if You are planning to create an application that requires accurate location tracing, You should fetch the location as in the "Vogella" method. If the current location is unavailable, you can try using the last known location (As a plan B :-)).